# How to chain functions into one sentence

Tags: javascript, html

So i have to write a program, which could chain function like this:
name("Adam").place("cinema").movie("xxx") expected output should be like this: Adam goes to Cinema to watch movie called xxx, what i have so far:

```
    var test = function(name){

        var self = {};
        console.log(name)

        function someFunc(where) {
            console.log("goes to cinema" + where)
            return self;
        }

        function someOtherFunc(what) {
            console.log("to watch movie" + what)
            return self;
        }   

        self.someFunc = someFunc;
        self.someOtherFunc = someOtherFunc;
        return self;

    }
 console.log(test("Adam").someFunc("cinema").someOtherFunc("xxx"));
```

But it gives me strings in different lines, and i want to be it in one sentence, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Each time you call console.log() in `someFunc` and `someOtherFunc` it will print on differently lines.

Comment: Yea, i figured it out, but where should i put it, to get that result in one line, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var test = function(message) {

  this.someFunc = function(where) {
    message += ` goes to ${where}`;
    return this; // Allow chaining
  }

  this.someOtherFunc = function(what) {
    message += ` to watch movie ${what}`;
    return this; // Allow chaining
  }

  this.value = function() {
    return message; //End chain
  }

  return this; // Start chain

}
console.log(test("Adam").someFunc("cinema").someOtherFunc("xxx").value());
//Adam goes to cinema to watch movie xxx
```

---

### Edit:

Is it possible to get that result without `.value()` ?

You can override `.toString()`.

> Every object has a toString() method that is automatically called when
>   the object is to be represented as a text value or when an object is
>   referred to in a manner in which a string is expected. By default, the
>   toString() method is inherited by every object descended from Object.
>   If this method is not overridden in a custom object, toString()
>   returns "[object type]", where type is the object type.

This would require to convert the object to string though.

```js
var test = function(message) {

  this.someFunc = function(where) {
    message += ` goes to ${where}`;
    return this;
  }

  this.someOtherFunc = function(what) {
    message += ` to watch movie ${what}`;
    return this;
  }

  this.toString = function() {
    return message;
  }

  return this;

}

console.log(`${ test("Adam").someFunc("cinema").someOtherFunc("xxx")}`);
```

Comment: is it possible to get that result without .value() ?

Comment: I included another alternative without using `.value()`, it still has a limitation though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need your functions to execute in that order, and produce a sentence that doesn't vary in order, you could do the following:

```
var test = function(name){
  var self = {
    message: name,
  };

  function someFunc(where) {
      self.message += " goes to cinema" + where;
      return self;
  }

  function someOtherFunc(what) {
      self.message += " to watch movie" + what;
      console.log(self.message);
  }   

  self.someFunc = someFunc;
  self.someOtherFunc = someOtherFunc;
  return self;
}

console.log(test("Adam").someFunc("cinema").someOtherFunc("xxx"));
```

Comment: This returns the sentence and `undefined`. It will not work if you remove one of the functions as well, since you are returning an object before `someOtherFunc`.

Comment: Hence, "and produce a sentence that doesn't vary in order." The asker asked how to make exactly that sentence, and that's what I gave him. I have no clue what he wants it for. You're more than welcome to produce a better answer, though!